# Does the complex conjugate just switch the sign in-between the numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a question about imaginary numbers and their complex conjugate.

My teacher denotes the complex conjugate to have a bar over it.
For example:
$\overline{3+5i} = 3 - 5i$

But does the complex conjugate just switch the sign in-between the numbers?

For example, would 
$\overline{-1 - i} = -1 + i$ ?

Comment: The complex conjugate of the complex number $a + bi$ is, by definition, the complex number $a - bi$. It changes the sign on the imaginary component only.

Comment: ah, so is my above example correct?
/ (-1 - i) = -1 + i.

Comment: $\overline{a+ib} := a-ib$ $ \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just switches the sign of the imaginary part of the number. Your example is correct.